# C++ declare derived class object inside of if-else and use it outside

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a (parent) class named `Alma` with the (virtual) function `Getwidth()` and two derived class of `Alma`, named `Birs` (with the special function `Getheight()`) and `Citrom` (with the special function `Getdepth()`). I want to declare an object - named `Attila` - which type is `Birs` or `Citrom` depending on a `bool`. Later, I want to use the common function `Getwidth()` and also the special functions (depending the `bool` mentioned).

My (not working) code:

```
/*...*/
/*Classes*/
class Alma{
  public: virtual int Getwidth() = 0;
  /*ect...*/
}

class Birs: public Alma{
  int Getwidth(){return 1;}
  public: int Getheight(){return 2;}
  /*ect...*/
}

class Citrom: public Alma{
  int Getwidth(){return 3;}
  public: int Getdepth(){return 4;}
  /*ect...*/
}
/*...*/
/*Using them*/
void Useobjects(){

/*Create object depending on bool*/
  if(b00lvar){
    Birs Andor();
    std::cout<<Andor.Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor.Getheight()<<std::endl;
  }else{
    Citrom Andor();
    std::cout<<Andor.Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor.Getdepth()<<std::endl;
  }

/*Using the common part of object*/  
  std::cout<<Andor.Getwidth()<<std::endl;

/*Using the special part of object*/
  if(b00lvar){
    std::cout<<Andor.Getheight()<<std::endl;
  }else{
    std::cout<<Andor.Getdepth()<<std::endl;
  } 

/*ect...*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case of polymorphic object handling. Just make sure you are familiar with that concept as well with pointers and references.

What you need is something looking like:

```
Alma* Andor;

 if(b00lvar){
    Andor = new Birs();
    std::cout<<Andor->Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor->Getheight()<<std::endl;
  }else{
    Andor = new Citrom();  
    std::cout<<Andor->Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor->Getdepth()<<std::endl;
  }
```

Next use `dynamic_cast` to get back to the derived types and finally of course do not forget to delete the object. But first read about those concepts.

Comment: @Richard Hodges This is a school level assignment, not production code. One should not dive into smart pointers without knowing first what a basic pointer feels like.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your reasoning. However I don't think we can make assumptions about the motivation of the OP who has presented the question. SO is here as an educational resource and as such, these answers will be read by possibly thousands of people. Since we may well end up working with someone who was influenced by one of them, I think we owe it to ourselves to teach people The Right Thing (tm), no?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a single object whose type is this or that, depending on something else. C++ doesn't work this way. C++ is a statically-typed language. This means that the type of every object is determined at compile time. Other languages, like Perl, or Javascript, are dynamically-typed, where the type of an object is determined at runtime, and a single object can be one thing, at one point, and something else at a different point.

But C++ does not work this way.

To do something like what you're trying to do, you have to refactor the code, and work with the virtual superclass. Something like this:

```
void UseObject(Alma &andor)
{
  /*Using the common part of object*/  
  std::cout<<andor.Getwidth()<<std::endl;

  /*Using the special part of object*/

  /* This part is your homework assignment */
}


void Useobjects(){

/*Create object depending on bool*/
  if(b00lvar){
    Birs andor;
    std::cout<<Andor.Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor.Getheight()<<std::endl;
    UseObject(andor);
  }else{
    Citrom andor;
    std::cout<<Andor.Getwidth()<<" "<<Andor.Getdepth()<<std::endl;
    UseObject(andor);
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to use two pointers, in this case passing two pointers to `UseObject()`. One of the two pointers will always be a `nullptr`, and the other one a pointer to the instantiated object, with `UseObject()` coded to deal with whatever object is passed in.

That's also possible, but will result in ugly code, and if I was an instructor teaching C++, I would mark down anyone who handed in code that did that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pointer semantic and type introspection with `dynamic_cast`. I extended your example to show how I would approach it.

Here is the [Demo](https://ideone.com/lrAfjn)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Alma{
public:
    virtual int Getwidth() = 0;
};

class Birs: public Alma{
public:
    int Getwidth()  { return 1; }
    int Getheight() { return 2; }
};

class Citrom: public Alma{
public:
    int Getwidth() { return 3; }
    int Getdepth() { return 4; }
};

shared_ptr<Alma> make_attila(bool birs)
{
    if (birs)
        return make_shared<Birs>();
    else
        return make_shared<Citrom>();
}

void test_attila(shared_ptr<Alma> attila)
{
    cout << "width: " << attila->Getwidth() << "\n";
    if (auto as_birs = dynamic_pointer_cast<Birs>(attila))
        cout << "height: " << as_birs->Getheight() << "\n";
    else if (auto as_citrom = dynamic_pointer_cast<Citrom>(attila))
        cout << "depth: " << as_citrom->Getdepth() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    shared_ptr<Alma> attila = make_attila(true);
    test_attila(attila);
    attila = make_attila(false);
    test_attila(attila);
    return 0;
}
```

Next step would be to make `make_attila` a template function taking the Derived class as a template parameter instead of a bool.

```
template <class Derived>
shared_ptr<Alma> make_attila()
{
   return make_shared<Derived>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. If you want to use it outside the `if`, you *will* have to declare it outside the `if`.
2. You *need* references or pointers for this kind of polymorphism.

```
unique_ptr<Alma> Andor;

if (b00lvar) {
  Andor = make_unique<Birs>();
} else {
  Andor = make_unique<Citrom>();
}

std::cout << Andor->Getwidth() << std::endl;
```

Some other answer suggested using `shared_ptr` but that's overkill here. 99% of the time `unique_ptr` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If the type of the object (Alma or Citrom) is decided at the startup, then it's a classic polymorphism, as other answers described:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218884/185881

What're you missing from your design is, to *name* the common ancestor with common behaviors (e.g. Gyumolcs).

If the object should once act as Alma and other times as Citrom, you should implement a single class, which have a flag or enum (ACT_AS_CITROM, ACT_AS_ALMA), or, if the behavior is limited to one method, then it should have a parameter, which tells which action to perform (alma-like or citrom-like).

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism isn't always the way to go if an object is known to be either a B or a C. In this case, a `boost::variant` is often more succinct.

Having said this, if you want to go down the polymorphic route it's important to remember something that will guide the design.

Polymorphic means *runtime polymorphic*. I.e. the program cannot know the real type of the object. It also cannot know the full set of possible types the object could be, since another developer could manufacture a type that your module's code knows nothing about. Furthermore, when using the Alma interface, the code *should not* need to know anything more. Invoking magic such as "I know it'll be a `Citrom` because the bool is true" is laying the foundations for a code maintenance nightmare a few weeks or months down the line. When done in commercial, production code, it results in expensive and embarrassing bug-hunts. Don't do that.

This argues that all relevant information about any object of type `Alma` must be available in the `Alma` interface.

In our case, the relevant information is whether it has the concept of height and/or depth.

In this case, we should probably include these properties in the base interface plus provide functions so that the program can query whether the property is valid before using it.

Here is something like your example written this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>


// separating out these optional properties will help me to reduce clutter in Alma

struct HeightProperty
{
    bool hasHeight() const { return impl_hasHeight(); }
    int getHeight() const { return impl_getHeight(); }

private:

    // provide default implementations
    virtual bool impl_hasHeight() const { return false; }
    virtual int impl_getHeight() const { throw std::logic_error("getHeight not implemented for this object"); }

};

struct DepthProperty
{
    bool hasDepth() const { return impl_hasDepth(); }
    int getDepth() const { return impl_getDepth(); }

private:

    virtual bool impl_hasDepth() const { return false; }
    virtual int impl_getDepth() const { throw std::logic_error("getDepth not implemented for this object"); }

};

class Alma : public HeightProperty, public DepthProperty
{
public:
    Alma() = default;
    virtual ~Alma() = default;

    // note: nonvirtual interface defers to private virtual implementation
    // this is industry best practice
    int getWidth() const { return impl_getWidth(); }
    const std::string& type() const {
        return impl_getType();
    }
private:
    virtual int impl_getWidth() const = 0;
    virtual const std::string& impl_getType() const = 0;

};

class Birs: public Alma
{
private:
    // implement the mandatory interface
    int impl_getWidth() const override { return 1; }
    const std::string& impl_getType() const override {
        static const std::string type("Birs");
        return type;
    }

    // implement the HeightProperty optional interface
    bool impl_hasHeight() const override { return true; }
    int impl_getHeight() const override { return 2; }
};

class Citrom: public Alma
{
private:
    // implement the mandatory interface
    int impl_getWidth() const override { return 3; }
    const std::string& impl_getType() const override {
        static const std::string type("Citrom");
        return type;
    }

    // implement the DepthProperty optional interface

    bool impl_hasDepth() const override { return true; }
    int impl_getDepth() const override { return 4; }
};

/*...*/
/*Using them*/

// generate either a Birs or a Citrom, but return the Alma interface
std::unique_ptr<Alma> make_alma(bool borc)
{
    if (borc) {
        return std::make_unique<Birs>();
    }
    else {
        return std::make_unique<Citrom>();
    }
}

void Useobjects()
{
    for (bool b : { true, false })
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Alma> pa = make_alma(b);

        std::cout << "this object's typeid name is " << pa->type() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "it's width is : " << pa->getWidth() << std::endl;

        if(pa->hasHeight()) {
            std::cout << "it's height is: " << pa->getHeight() << std::endl;
        }
        if(pa->hasDepth()) {
            std::cout << "it's depth is: " << pa->getDepth() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Useobjects();
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
this object's typeid name is Birs
it's width is : 1
it's height is: 2
this object's typeid name is Citrom
it's width is : 3
it's depth is: 4
```